# Slim framework não está direcionando a rota para login

Tags: php, slimframework

Boa tarde! Estou fazendo um projeto do curso de PHP7, mas estou com o seguinte problema:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Slim\Http\get_magic_quotes_gpc() in C:lojavirtual\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Http\Util.php:59 Stack trace: #0 C:lojavirtual\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Http\Request.php(240): Slim\Http\Util::stripSlashesIfMagicQuotes(Array) #1 C:lojavirtual\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Middleware\MethodOverride.php(88): Slim\Http\Request->post('_METHOD') #2 C:lojavirtual\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\MiddlewarelPrettyExceptions.php(67): Slim\MiddlewarelMethodOverride->call() #3 C:lojavirtual\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Slim.php(1159): Slim\Middleware\PrettyExceptions->call() #4 C:\lojavirtual\index.php(44): Slim\Slim->run() #5 {main} thrown in C:lojavirtual\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\Http\Util.php on line 59
```

<sup>[Imagem do erro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cqkC.png)</sup>

Os códigos que foram criados:

USER.php

```
class User {
public static function login($login, $password){
    $sql = new Sql();
    $results = $sql->select("SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE deslogin = :LOGIN", array(
        ":LOGIN"=>$login
    ));
    if (count($results) === 0)
    {
        throw new \Exception("Falha no Login!");
    }
    $data = $results[0];
    if (password_verify($password, $data["despassword"]) === true)
    {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setiduser($data["iduser"]);

    } else {
        throw new \Exception("Falha no Login!");
    }
}
}
```

Model.php

```
<?php
namespace Hcode;

class Model {
    private $values = [];
    public function __call($name, $args){
        $method = substr($name, 0, 3);
        $fieldName = substr($name, 3, strlen($name));

        var_dump($method, $fieldName);
    }
}
?>
```

Rota do Slim

```
$app->post('/admin/login', function() {
    User::login($_POST["login"], $_POST["password"]);
    header("Location: /admin");
    exit;
```

Comment: Estranho a função `get_magic_quotes_gpc` estar sendo chamada aqui... Qual a versão do Slim Framework você está utilizando? Ou então, por onde você baixou ela?

Comment: Boa tarde! Desculpa a demora pra responder, mas estou utilizando a versão 2.0

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que você deva ter estar com a diretiva `magic_quotes_gpc` desabilitada na sua máquina. Você precisa habilitá-la no *php.ini*:

```ini
; Magic quotes para dados vindos via GET/POST/Cookie.
magic_quotes_gpc = On
    
; Magic quotes para dados gerados em tempo de execução,ex.: dados vindo de SQL, de chamadas à exec(), etc.
magic_quotes_runtime = On
    
; Usar magic quotes no estilo Sybase (escapar ' com '' ao invés de \').
magic_quotes_sybase = On
```

A função `get_magic_quotes_gpc` está [obsoleta](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.get-magic-quotes-gpc.php) desde o PHP 7.4.0 e mesmo com a correção acima você vai continuar recebendo uma mensagem como esta:

```
Deprecated: Function get_magic_quotes_gpc() is deprecated in...
```

Claro que como você está seguindo um curso, é melhor utilizar a mesma versão do Framework do professor mesmo (vale verificar se a que ele está usando é a mesma que a sua também), porém, o ideal para projetos "reais" é utilizar a [nova](https://www.slimframework.com/) versão do Slim, por conta desta e de outras melhorias.